# Kendo grid scroll not working on mobile browser

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo grid MVC, scroll is not working on mobile browser. Not able to scroll on mobile but working fine on desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

Style touch-action set as none by Kendo, which was causing issue.
As an workaround added below code in document ready...

```
$(".k-selectable").css("touch-action", "auto");
```

This solved my issue.
Sharing this to save someone time probably.